# Limiting Group Items in the Content Query WebPart

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, web-parts, cqwp

Can I [Limit Group Items in the Content Query WebPart](http://www.wagesworld.com/jwages/default.aspx) so that the output is

```
<h2>Group Header</h2>
<ul>
<li>Item One</li>
<li>Item Two</li>
<li>Item Three</li>
<li>See More</li>
</ul>
```

I've followed the linked tutorial which works fine, I just can't get the correct output. In particular the two `UL` tags.

Comment: Can you provide input XML and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The containing structure (a table with class `cbq-layout-main`) is defined in `ContentQueryMain.xsl` file, the `OuterTemplate` template. However, if you modify it, all of your ContentQueryWebpart-s will be modified.

So you have to create a custom definition for main query (e.g. `ContentQueryMain-cust.xsl`), then follow this tutorial: http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/kyles/Lists/Posts/ViewPost.aspx?ID=3&RootFolder=%2FBlogs%2Fkyles%2FLists%2FPosts

Comment: Thanks naivists. I already had made a copy of the main.xsl. The issue was that putting in the <ul> tags would make it appear above the <h2> header when editing the main.xsl. I'll have another look and see if I've missed something. cheers

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I was updating the main.xsl which was failing becuase the xml mark up was not valid even though the ouput would have been. To get around this I needed to use <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class='block'&gt;</xsl:text>

Comment: I did a quick post if anyone wants to know what I ended up doing http://udigg.com.au/?p=163